# binding dropdownlist in mvc3 Razor(default Dropdownlist value is not selected)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am binding dropdownlist in mvc3 Razor.
My problem is its not showing default Dropdownlist value selected.An Empty space is shown.
Code is given below:

```
  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MainHeadingFont, new SelectList(Model.lst_FontType, "Value", "Text"), new { @class = "inputPage7Select" })
```

CollectionList is passed from Model:

```
public List<SelectListItem> lst_FontType
    {
        get
        {
            FontType.RemoveRange(0, FontType.Count);
            FontType.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "\"Gill Sans MT\", Arial, sans-serif", Value = "\"Gill Sans MT\", Arial, sans-serif", Selected = true });
            FontType.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "\"Palatino Linotype\", Times, serif", Value = "\"Palatino Linotype\", Times, serif" });
            FontType.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "\"Times New Roman\", Times, serif", Value = "\"Times New Roman\", Times, serif" });
            return FontType;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In the controller action rendering this view:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = ...
    model.MainHeadingFont = "\"Palatino Linotype\", Times, serif";
    return View(model);
}
```

This will automatically preselect the second element of the ddl.